# How to display button after completed Lottie animation in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, lottie

I want to Flutter Framework show the user a button when the Lottie animation is over
[Like the image below that appears after the end of the button animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Eb33.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StatefulWidget and use a boolean isLoading = true then if you await for the animation to finish and set the isLoading to false you can use the following syntax

```
if(!isLoading) RaisedButton(child:Text("Got It")
```